# Dynamic dropdown option load dissapears html modal dialog

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

My Html form has dropdown which load dynamic options using api request. I'm using google HTML Service to link google app script with html file. My problem is my modal dialog getting disappear as soon as it appears.

======== Script ========

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Call API')
      .addItem('Display results','html')
      .addToUi();
}

function html(){
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('load');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Input API Creddentials');

}

function getClients() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://myurl does here");
   var fact = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var optionsHTML = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < fact.length-1;i+=1) {
   optionsHTML.push(fact[i].clientId.client);
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(optionsHTML);
  return optionsHTML;
 }
```

======= HTML File ====

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
       <base target="_top">
     </head>
     <body>
       <form >
  <div>
  <select id="optionList" name="optionList">
    <option>Loading...</option>    
  </select>

  </div> 
  Username:
  <input type="text" name="username"> <br />
  Password:
  <input type="password" name="password"> <br />
  <input type="button" value="OK" onclick="google.script.run.callNumbers(this.parentNode);google.script.host.editor.focus();" />
</form>
  </body>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
    // The code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
    $(function () {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildOptionList)
            .getClients();
    });

    function buildOptionList(clients) {
        var list = $('#optionList');
        list.empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < clients.length; i++) {
            list.append(new Option(clients[i]));
        }
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs due to

```
// The code in this function runs when the page is loaded.
$(function () {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildOptionList)
        .getClients();
});
```

because `getClients()` shows an alert and Google Apps Script doesn't allow to have a Google Sheets UI alert and modal dialog shown simultaneosly.